# Technologies For Interactive Websites and Animations

Tags: html, html5-canvas, webgl, interactive

I'm looking into making interactive websites in the near future.  My question is what are the different technologies I can utilize if I wanted to make an interactive web page?  I know HTML5 now has the ability to draw to a Canvas, including in 3D.

Are there any good tutorials I can look at.  Below is an example website I was looking at.  What technologies do you think were used in this app?  I looked at the HTML source code and only saw Javascript files.

I understand this might be HTML5, but if so, what frameworks might they be using?

[Arms Globe](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/projects/armsglobe/)

[Pitch Interactive](http://drones.pitchinteractive.com/)

Comment: I'm still new here so please, if you down vote me let me know why so I don't make the same mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website's interactivity is accomplish only with javascript.

You have 2 ways to make an interactive website: unsing Javascript, or using HTML5/CSS3 (you can also create your website interactivity by using Flash, but flash belong to the past ...)

Comment: That seems really tedious to make that using just Javascript.  What about the animations and such?

Comment: They are using some Frameworks like JQuery, but yes everything is in Javascript. Javascript is a very powerfull language.